# How to check if `Any(not Any?)` is nil or not in swift

Tags: swift

I'm working with the `Mirror` in swift, I found `Mirror.Child` is very strange, the label is nullable, but the value seems not nullable.

```
public typealias Child = (label: String?, value: Any)
```

I don't know how to check if the value is nil or not.

```
let b: Bool? = true
let a: Any = b
print(a == nil) // false
```

I have one solution:

```
print(String(describing: a) == "nil") // true
```

but it is obviously not a good solution.

what is the best way to check if `a` is nil or not ?

**Let me put more detail,**

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: object) // object can be any object.
for child in mirror.children {
    guard let label = child.label else {
        continue
    }
    // how to check if the value is nil or not here ?
    setValue(child.value, forKey: label)
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just check that `b` is true or false?

Comment: @Jake as I said, the real code is about `Mirror`, I can't have the `b` directly in the real code.

Comment: `guard let testValue = b else { return }`

Comment: With `let b: Bool? = true` if you use `let a: Any = b` compiler will show warning to add a default value. Rather you can use option value of any as `let a: Any? = b` and can check as `if a == nil { }`

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal, that's not what I want.

Comment: I don't don't know if `Mirror` works but looking into your updated qustion, you can check it with `label` as `guard let label = child.label, let value = child.value else { continue }` and use it as `setValue(value, forKey: label) `

Comment: I have yet to find a situation where `Mirror` is the tool you want. If you're trying to create a reflection system, you will find that `Mirror` is inadequate to the problem. It is not currently possible to build a reflection system in Swift (which is why Codable had to have special compiler support; it's not possible to write it in Swift).

Comment: I'm also confused by your use of `setValue(_:forKey:)`. That's part of the ObjC runtime, unless you have your own version of it. `Mirror` and the ObjC runtime are not particularly compatible. If you want to do refection only of NSObject-subclasses, that has extensive support through the ObjC runtime.

Comment: @RobNapier It's `NSManagedObject`

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal this doesn't work `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Any'` .  the `label` is not optional.

Comment: You don't want `Mirror`. You want to dig into the ObjC runtime. For example, `class_getProperty`, `class_getInstanceMethod`, etc.

Comment: why not mirror? it works fine.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. If this is `NSManagedObject`, it's easier than that. Look at `NSManagedObjectModel` and particularly `NSEntityDescription`. Core Data will tell you most of what you want to know about managed objects.

Comment: @RobNapier I see, `setValue(child.value, forKey: label)` is for `NSManagedObject`, the `object` in `Mirror(reflecting: object)`  is a swift object.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Using `if case`:**

You can use `if case Optional<Any>.none = a` to test if `a` is `nil`:

```
var b: Bool?
var a = b as Any
if case Optional<Any>.none = a {
    print("nil")
} else {
    print("not nil")
}
```

> > ```
> > nil
> > ```

```
b = true
a = b as Any
if case Optional<Any>.none = a {
    print("nil")
} else {
    print("not nil")
}
```

> > ```
> > not nil
> > ```

---

**Using `switch`:**

You can use the pattern test with `switch` as well:

```
var b: Bool?
var a = b as Any

switch a {
case Optional<Any>.none:
    print("nil")
default:
    print("not nil")
}
```

> > ```
> > nil
> > ```

Comment: Nice answer, but might be clearer using`switch` rather than `if case`

Comment: Thanks @AshleyMills.  I added `switch` to the answer.

Comment: Since `Optional` is `enum`, i think it's worthwhile to point out that you can also do the opposite `case` like this for example `guard case Optional<Any>.some = b else { return }`