# Why casting nil value as Any is not considered as nil?

Tags: swift, casting, any

In Swift, casting an optional constant to `Any` is legal, for example:

```
let nilValue: String? = nil
let any: Any = nilValue
```

without the need to declare `any` as optional Any (`Any?`)

however, the surprising result for me is that:

```
print(any == nil) // false
print(any) // nil
```

Which seems to be conflict.

I could find a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255038/5501940) to check whether `any` is `nil` or not, however my question is what is the reason for such a behavior?

Please **note that** if I declared `any` as:

```
let any: Any? = nilValue
```

the output of

```
print(any == nil)
```

would be `true`.

Comment: @vacawama thanks mate. Do you think it might be better if I delete the question?

Comment: That's up to you.  Your question has a different title and might make it easier for another person to find the answer when searching.

Comment: It would be a good idea to up vote the duplicate's answer though if you haven't already.

Comment: @vacawama ya sure! I prefer to do after I carefully read it 

Comment: @vacawama I think I got it. However, do you think that is it logical to be able to cast an optional string -for instance- as non-optional Any? I mean what's the point of it if (`any == nil`) never succeeds?

Comment: The point of `Any` is that it can hold anything. It would change the definition of `Any` to say it can be anything but optionals. Optionals are a special syntactic sugar around the underlying enum implementation. The Swift language requires a var to be an optional in order to compare it to `nil`. My advice is to avoid using `Any` whenever possible, and definitely avoid putting an optional value into a non-Optional `Any` var.

Comment: Many of the struggles around this involve the interaction with Objective-C. Swift changed from treating `id` as `AnyObject` to `Any` to make other interactions nicer, but resulted in sometimes treating optionals as `Any`.  The compromise was to add a warning to the compiler if you try to assign an optional to an `Any` var.  The compiler requires you to cast the value to `Any` to say "yeah, I know this is troublesome, but I really need it in this case".  An example of when this is needed is trying to print an optional without unwrapping it: `print(someOptionalValue as any)`.